# Is there a way to run code during an update for an iOS app?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I have recently discovered an error in an app I have previously released for iOS. I am saving something with an incorrect metadata variable which causes a notification to be monthly instead of daily.

This is trivial to fix, it just involves looping through all the currently saved objects and changing a 1 to a 0. However it would be preferable to me to be able to do this during the update that fixes the error. Is there a way then of running code as part of an update?

Otherwise I imagine the next best way of solving the problem would be to run the loop the next time the app is opened.

I have looked around online and have only found solutions which involve running one off code on app start up. I am therefore wondering if I am missing something because this seems to be the sort of thing that a lot of apps will need to have happen to them if they need to reconfigure how their data is saved or equivalent.

Comment: It cannot be done. You have to do the one-time fix upon first app launch after update.

Comment: Is it using Core Data ? If you have made changes to anything in the DB between versions it will attempt lightweight migration which you can override to 'assist' the built in migration with anything custom you need to do, at this point you could do it.

Comment: I'm actually using an NSKeyedArchiver, so your answer below looks ideal!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not using core data and overriding the light weight migration to make an changes needed there, then the only way is to use User Defaults and check for a var you know does not exist, run the code, then add the var so as to not run it again.

```
func updateDB() {
    if !UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: MyProject.DBFixKey) {
        // Fix DB

        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: MyProject.DBFixKey)
    }
}
```